# Can I use an HP Smary Array SAS Controller Card In Non-HP Server?

Tags: raid, storage, sas

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Proliant raid controller in a PC](https://serverfault.com/questions/359261/proliant-raid-controller-in-a-pc)

There are a bunch of cheap HP Smart Array SAS controller cards on ebay and I'm wondering if they will work with non HP servers (motherboards) and drives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, yes you can although you will obviously have to install the right drivers and almost certainly will lose a degree of instrumentation and alarming but yes they will do the basics just fine.